# Adding element to el in backbone

Tags: backbone.js

This is source code that viewing from my web page :

```
<div id="webcontainer">
    <div id="webheader"></div>
    <div id="webbody">  
    <div id="webbodycontainer"></div>       
    </div>
    <div id="webfooter"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the view :

```
var RegisterView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el : $("#webbodycontainer"),
  initialize : function(){

  },
  events : {
    'click #register' : 'registerUser'
  },
  registerUser : function(){
    alert("hi");
  },
  render : function(){
    $("#webheader").html(headerTem);
    $("#webfooter").html(footerTem);

    var _registerDes = _.template(RegisterDescriptionTem);
    this.$el.append(_registerDes);
  }
});
return RegisterView;
```

`_registerDes` content is shown in the webpage but not in a DOM, So `click` event on a `#register` button is not fired. Have I missed something?

Here is `RegisterDescriptionTem` template :

```
<div class="registerleftpanel">
//....
</div>
<div id="rightpanel" style="float:right; padding-right:10px;">
  <div id="registerPanel" style="width: 528px;">
    <div class="cartheadertitle loginheadertitle">Register New Account</div>
    <br>
    <form id="registerForm" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
            //......
            <div style="position: relative; float: left; left: 90px; top: -3px;">       
               <input type="button" value="Register" class="btn" id="register">
            </div> 
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that `_registerDes` will be a function so you almost certainly want to say `this.$el.append(_registerDes())`. You can hand a function to [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/#append-functionindex--html) but you rarely want to do that with an Underscore template function. Any chance of seeing a minimal demo on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @muistooshort : I tried to import it in http://jsfiddle.net/Y9tEa/, but the view did not render.

Comment: Seems to work fine if you set it up properly and use up to date versions of Underscore and Backbone: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/6g9pB/